# Private static methods in NodeJS v12.13.0 - syntax error

Tags: node.js, static, private, static-methods

As described in the JavaScript Reference by Mozilla here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_static_methods

This is how private static methods should work:

```js
class Foo {
  static #privateStaticMethod() {
    return 42;
  }
}
```

However, when using this in NodeJS v12.13.0, the following syntax error is thrown:

```
static #privateStaticMethod() {
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../foo.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
```

Having a look at the [browser compatibility page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_class_fields), private static methods *should* be supported since v12.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table states that Private Static **fields** are supported, not methods.

In node `13.2.0` it's working under `--harmony-private-methods` flag

[[class] implement static private methods](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+log/branch-heads/7.9/?s=727668298ebdc1817fd4783ac95941a83223f28f) was added in v8 `7.9`. That version of v8 was [added to Node 13.2.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases/tag/v13.2.0)

---

Using the flag, in Node `12.13.0` you won't get a `SyntaxError` but a `TypeError` when trying to access the method

```
TypeError: Read of private field Foo from an object which did not contain the field
```

---

**v8 issue:** [Fully implemented behind flag](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=8330)

Comment: I actually ended up using arrow functions. They work as private static members:                      `static #privateStaticMethod = () => {
    return 42;
  };`